# Why Java doesn't reset the values of the inner loop after a break statement?

Tags: java, loops

I'm currently struggling understanding this loop:

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int i=0, j=0;
        X1: for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            X2: for(j = 3; j > 0; j--){
                if(i < j) continue X1;
                else break X2;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(i+" "+j);
    }
}
```

So far I know that the values of the variable will be:

```
 0 3 
 1 3 
 2 3
```

and finally will print `3 3`.

After the third iteration the condition on `X1` will be false resulting in an interruption of the loop statement. While it's clear to me why the value of `i` is equal to 3, I do not understand why the value of j is 3 as well. Initially the value of j is `0`, when we enter in the loop is `3`, but in the last iteration we do not enter really in the `X2` loop, since `i<3` evaluate false. So the question is why the compiler "save" the value of `k` ? And even if the compiler save the value of `j` from the previous iteration should be `2` ...

Comment: "*I do not understand why the value of j is 3 as well.*" - You initialized it with `3` in the head of the loop. When the inner loop ends, `j` goes out of scope. If the inner loop is entered again later on, a new `j` is created.

Comment: Step through the code step by step in a debugger to see exactly how it goes, it will show it the best to you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Also, please read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: You dont even need a debugger. Take a pen and a piece of paper, and run your algorithm yourself. That is how you "debug" problems that are so small (that you can easily run them manually).

Comment: The question is pure theoretical, I'm studying for the OCA, the point here is understand the code, not starting a debate about optimisation or unreachable lines. Thank's to everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`j--` is dead code here and will never be reached.  Think about how the code works for a moment here:

```
X2: for(j = 3; j > 0; j--){
    if(i < j) continue X1;
    else break X2;
}
```

If one situation you continue to the outer loop, in the other situation you break out of this loop.  This loop actually never even goes past a single iteration so you might as well just write this like this:

```
int i=0, j=0;
X1: for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    j = 3;
    if(i < j) continue X1;  //This line does nothing at this point as well since the loop will iterate anyway
}
```

This is exactly the same as your current code, which clearly shows `j` will stay at `3`.

Comment: No point in writing `if (condition) continue X1;` as the last statement in the X1 loop: it will do exactly the same without.

Comment: @Andy Turner Yeah I left it in to try and keep it similar with the `X1` so he can see the important changes since you can really reduce it all the way to `int i = 3, j = 3;`.  But I'll make a change for it.

Answer (score 1):

`for(j = 3; j > 0; j--)`
You are setting `j=3`. `j--` is not run until the next j loop, that never occurs, so it cannot be 2.

Answer (score 0):

```
else break X2;
```

and

```
j--
```

are never being reached.

'i' can never be 3 within the loop since the outer loop's condition is i < 3, and therefor the inner loop can only perform

```
if(i < j) continue X1;
```

since 'j' always starts at 3 and i <= 2. is always true. So 'j' never changes value, and the outer loop breaks when i = 3, resulting in, "3 3".

```
i j
0 3
1 3
2 3
break occurs;
print i + j;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Initially the value of j is 0, when we enter in the loop is 3, but in the last iteration we do not enter really in the X2 loop, since i<3 evaluate false. So the question is why the compiler "save" the value of k ?

j is declared at the first line in main. This means that it will remain in scope and retain any modifications until main ends and the variable is destroyed.

> And even if the compiler save the value of j from the previous iteration should be 2.

As you said above, the value of j from the last iteration of the loop was 3 not 2. When you continue X1 the j-- was never executed.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the dead code as others mentioned. You should debug your program by going step by step I don't know which IDE you are using but it probably provides this feature.

However, I want to advice you to not use continue and break statements. It is highly discouraged by the instructors. They cause spaghetti programming and confusions like you have.

Comment: Thank you, I'm sorry but I've to disagree. In some context breaching statements are needful, and by the way I'm studying for the OCA, I'm asking cause I have to clarify each shady doubts I might have.

Comment: Actually, no.
You don't need them: 
-You can add another condition to your loop instead of break
and
-You can add an if/else block instead of continue
in your loop.